# API for mobile apps, should it have colors in it?

Tags: api-design

Recently in our team we had a discussion about whether to have colors in API responses. For example

```
{
  "message": "Hello",
  "color": "red"
}
```

versus

```
{
  "message": "Hello",
  "type": "danger"
}
```

For the first option pros are

1. If you need to change color of some element, you don't have to re-compile and submit again your app to AppStore

Cons are

1. You cannot push all colors to the API, some of them still will be hardcoded.
2. If you change one color, you will have to change all other similar colors, otherwise you are at risk of having Christmas-tree app, with bunch of slightly different red colors.

For the second option pros are

1. You have purely information based API, you decide yourself how your ui should looks like

cons are

1. If you need to change some color, you need to re-compile your app and publish it again to AppStore, which sometimes may take a while

Dear friends, what do you think about those two different approaches? Please give some arguments to either prove my opinion or dodge it. How other big companies design their APIs? I never seen API providing colors, however I haven't seen a lot of APIs.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An API is designed to provide a way to access pure data, without any UI content, therefore, second option is more "correct", becouse it only specify type and not how it should look. With this option, anything could consume your API and decide how every message type should look.

Answer (score 1):

As Miller explained, API should be independent from UI part means you should always fetch data from API to UI and then take decision from UI module what to do with that.

I think you are not going to change color for any message that frequently like danger is always RED and good is always GREEN.

So don't worry about re-compile other stuff. Most of the cases, you are going to add color instead of change.

If you still want to discuss more then please explain your use case and application in details.